# Pthread and gcc compiling issue on OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, pthreads

I have a script that compiles fine on Linux (Ubuntu 11.04), but not on OS X (Lion).

```
gcc -pthread -o hw1 hw1.c 
hw1.c:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘barr’
hw1.c: In function ‘__syncthreads’:
hw1.c:53: error: ‘barr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
hw1.c:53: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
hw1.c:53: error: for each function it appears in.)
hw1.c:54: error: ‘PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
hw1.c: In function ‘parallel_psum’:
hw1.c:94: error: ‘barr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
hw1.c:107: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Here's the first 22 lines of the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* create thread argument struct for thr_func() */
typedef struct _thread_data_t {
    int tid;
    int* ints;
    int* sums;
    int num_ints;
    int* temp;
} thread_data_t;

const int MIN_RAND_INT = 1;
const int MAX_RAND_INT = 65000;

// pthreads barrier variable
pthread_barrier_t barr;
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Seems that pthread_barrier_t is not defined.

Comment: This is a type defined by the pthread library from what I understand

Comment: OSX maynot have `pthred_barrier_t`. Some hint about this has been mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640853/performance-test-sem-t-v-s-dispatch-semaphore-t-and-pthread-once-t-v-s-dispat) question

Comment: Well, that clarifies that. Linux for the win :) thanks

Comment: Yes, OS X seems somewhat to be a POSIX frozen around 2001. Helping people to write modern standard compliant code doesn't seem to be their first goal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [info about pthread_barriers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) on opengroup.org, barriers are defined in the *optional* part of POSIX standard; the name of option is "*(ADVANCED REALTIME THREADS)*", sometimes more exact referred as "BAR, barriers (real-time)".

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap02.html

> The system may support one or more options (see Options) denoted by the following symbolic constants:

```
_POSIX_BARRIERS
```

So, only if the _POSIX_BARRIERS macro is defined as positive number, you can use pthread_barrier_t or pthread_barrier_wait.

Mac OS X is POSIX Compliant, but full list of implemented options is not available online. [There is a letter](http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2006/Mar/msg00021.html) in apple mainling list from 2006, which says there is no barriers in Mac OS X.

I know that Solaris had some problems with pthread_barrier too.

Answer (score 2):

Just like osgx mentioned, barriers are not implemented on OS X, but you can always implement it or just use [this](http://www.howforge.com/implementing-barrier-in-pthreads) implementation. Quick note on the previous implementation, you can use the macro that osgx mentioned, _POSIX_BARRIERS, instead of the ones on the blog, like this `#if !defined _POSIX_BARRIERS || _POSIX_BARRIERS < 0`