# How to tell netbeans information on pthread_barrier_t

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, pthreads

I can't seem to get netbeans to recognize the pthread_barrier_t type.  I can type in `#include<pthread.h>` okay, but no luck on pthread_barrier_t.

The following is the build and the error:

> g++ -lpthread   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o
>   build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp main.cpp:32: error:
>   'pthread_barrier_t' does not name a type

I am using Netbeans 7.1 and I am on Mac OSX 10.7.2
I can create threads without any compile issues.

```
bool isNotInSteadyState()
{
    int rc = 0;
    threadData threadDataArray[NUM_THREADS];
    int dataArrayCount = 0;
    if (NUM_THREADS < ((PLATE_SIZE - 2) * (PLATE_SIZE - 2)))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < PLATE_SIZE - 1; i += sqrt(NUM_THREADS))
        {
           for (int j = 1; j < PLATE_SIZE - 1; j += sqrt(NUM_THREADS))
           {
                threadDataArray[dataArrayCount].endY = i + sqrt(NUM_THREADS) - 1;
                threadDataArray[dataArrayCount].x = i;
                threadDataArray[dataArrayCount].endY = j + sqrt(NUM_THREADS) - 1;
                threadDataArray[dataArrayCount++].y = j;
                pthread_t* thread;

                int pthread_create(thread, NULL,isNotInSteadyStateCheckRunInParallel, &threadDataArray[dataArrayCount]);
                if (dataArrayCount >= NUM_THREADS)
                {
                    //pthread_barrier_init(pthread_barrier_t * barrier,
              //const pthread_barrierattr_t *restrict attr, NUM+THREADS);
                }
                if (rc != 0)
                {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Steady State check failed!\n");
                }
          }
       }
    }    

}
```

Thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't use netbeans so I don't really know what you are asking but pthread_barrier_t isn't a command, it is a type.

Comment: I changed the terminology so it is more correct

Comment: Do you mean you can get some sort of 'IntelliSense' in Netbeans or that you get a compiler/build error if you try to use `pthread_barrier_t`?  If the latter, please give details on the error, the version of the tools, and the platform being used.

Comment: You can get an 'IntelliSense' in Netbeans.  I also have a build error when I try to use it

Comment: And all other references to pthread entities are ok?  Maybe you should show a bit of code.

Comment: I used openMP with it earlier and it worked just fine.  I'll show some more code.

Comment: Oh. This link might be part of the problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920803/pthread-and-gcc-compiling-issue-on-os-x  And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640853/performance-test-sem-t-v-s-dispatch-semaphore-t-and-pthread-once-t-v-s-dispat  You may be SOL.

Comment: put that as your answer.  I will check it off.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the offer but it really isn't an answer.  osgx's answer is more appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [info about pthread_barriers](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/pthread_barrier_wait.html) on opengroup.org, barriers are defined in the **optional** part of POSIX 1003.1 edition 2004; the name of option is "*(ADVANCED REALTIME THREADS)*", sometimes more exact referred as "BAR, barriers (real-time)".

All POSIX options are listed [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap02.html)

```
2.1.3 POSIX Conformance
POSIX System Interfaces
```

> The system may support one or more options (see Options) denoted by the following symbolic constants:

```
_POSIX_BARRIERS
```

So, only if the _POSIX_BARRIERS macro is defined as positive number, you can use pthread_barrier_t or pthrad_barrier_wait.

Mac OS X is POSIX Compliant, but I can't find full list of options implemented. I know that Solaris has problems with pthread_barrier too. [There is a post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2006/Mar/msg00021.html) in apple mainling list from 2006. It says that there are no barriers in Mac OS X

Comment: Good to know.  There seem to be a fair amount of confusion about this.