# C pthread_barriers in netbeans (cygwin)

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin, pthreads, barrier

I want to program in netbeans some C tasks from school. They gave us task where we must use pthread_barrier. So I downloaded netbeans and cygwin with gcc, g++, gdb and make. In `pthreads.h` isn't any `pthread_barrier_t` etc. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042780/how-to-tell-netbeans-information-on-pthread-barrier-t) I found "barriers are defined in the optional part of POSIX 1003.1 edition 2004". Qustion is how can I use barriers in netbeans with cygwin?

**Some code:**

```
//#define _POSIX_BARRIERS 1 
//I don't get it what they mean 
//"only if the _POSIX_BARRIERS macro is defined as positive number,
//you can use pthread_barrier_t"

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

// declaration of the barrier
pthread_barrier_t a_barrier; // err: Unable to resolve identifier pthread_barrier_t.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin does not currently support `pthread_barrier_*`, so you will not be able to compile or run code requiring those on Cygwin.